# ERROR: Teradata execute: Numeric overflow occurred during computation

Tags: sas, teradata, volatile

I've got this error: Teradata execute: Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

I have read the similar questions on this forum but still can't understand what should I do to resolve the problem.
I supposed that the reason is that I have computation on step when i devide NATIONAL_AMOUNT on DEBT_EXPENSE.

After using CAST there was no resolving still.
Has anyone thoughts? Please help me.
I think that the problem is here:

```
    EXECUTE (create multiset volatile table Debt_&mon. AS 
    (SELECT 
              t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
              t1.REGION,
              t1.SEGMENT,
              t1.ACC_METH,
              COUNT(t1.ACC_N) as Count_ACC_N,
              SUM(t1.NATIONAL_UNPAID) AS NATIONAL_UNPAID,
              SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as DEBT_EXPENSE,
              SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as NATIONAL_AMOUNT,
              (case when SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT)=0 then 0 else (cast(SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as Decimal(20,6))/cast(SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as Decimal(20,6)) end) as 'РСДЗ/Д'n,
              (case when SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE)=0 then 0 else cast(SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as Decimal(20,6))/cast(SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as Decimal(20,6)) end) as 'Д/ДЗ'n

           FROM Prev_Debt_&mon. t1
           LEFT JOIN CLC_&mon. t2 on 
                t1.REGION=t2.REGION and
                t1.SEGMENT=t2.SEGMENT and
                t1.ACC_METH=t2.ACC_METH
           GROUP BY t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, t1.REGION, t1.SEGMENT, t1.ACC_METH)

    WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;)
    by teradata;
```

======================The full code below====================================

```
EXECUTE (create multiset volatile table CLC_&mon. AS 
(SELECT 
          t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
          t1.REGION,
          Case when t2.SEGMENT is Null then 'NEW' else t2.SEGMENT end as "SEGMENT",
          t1.ACC_METH,
          COUNT(t1.ACC_N) as Count_ACC_N,
          SUM(t1.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) AS NATIONAL_AMOUNT,
          SUM(t1.NATIONAL_AMOUNT)/COUNT(t1.ACC_N) as 'ARPaU'n

       FROM UAT_V_BASE.RA_FCLC_ACC t1
       LEFT JOIN prd_sbx_general.&login._LIST_MK_2 t2 ON (t1.MARKET_CATEGORY=t2.MARKET_CATEGORY)
       GROUP BY t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, t1.REGION, "SEGMENT", t1.ACC_METH
       WHERE SEGMENT in ('B2C','B2B','VIP','OTHER')
             AND t1.ACC_METH in (1, 2)
             AND TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH between &firstmonth. and &lastmonth.
             AND MRGN_ID=&MR.)
WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;)
by teradata;

create table CLC_&mon. as select 
      TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH FORMAT=Date9.,
      REGION FORMAT=FSRGC.,
      SEGMENT FORMAT=$9.,
      ACC_METH FORMAT=F78C.,
      Count_ACC_N,
      NATIONAL_AMOUNT FORMAT=NUMX16.2 LABEL="(Сумма начислений с учетом налогов), RUB)",
      'ARPaU'n
from connection to teradata
(select distinct
      TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
      REGION,
      SEGMENT,
      ACC_METH,
      Count_ACC_N,
      NATIONAL_AMOUNT,
      'ARPaU'n
    GROUP BY TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, REGION, SEGMENT, ACC_METH, Count_ACC_N, NATIONAL_AMOUNT,'ARPaU'n
    ORDER BY TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, REGION, SEGMENT, ACC_METH
from CLC_&mon.);

EXECUTE (create multiset volatile table Prev_Debt_&mon. AS 
(SELECT 
          t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
          t1.REGION,
          Case when t2.SEGMENT is Null then 'NEW' else t2.SEGMENT end as "SEGMENT",
          t1.ACC_METH,
          t1.BASE_AGE,
          Case when t1.BASE_AGE=-1 then 'ОДЗ'
               when t1.BASE_AGE=3 then 'CДЗ'
               else 'Другая ДЗ'
               end as "Tип ДЗ",
          Case when t1.NATIONAL_UNPAID between 0 and 200000 then '0...200'
               when t1.NATIONAL_UNPAID between 200000 and 500000 then '200...500'
               else '> 500' end as 'Amount_of_Debt'n,
          t1.ACC_N,
          SUM(t1.NATIONAL_UNPAID) AS NATIONAL_UNPAID,
          Case when t1.EXCEPTED_FROM_BUH eq 0 then (t1.NT_BUH_DELTA + t1.NT_WRITE_OFF)
               else t1.NT_WRITE_OFF_COLLFIN
               end AS DEBT_EXPENSE

       FROM UAT_V_BASE.RA_FDEB_ACC t1
       LEFT JOIN prd_sbx_general.&login._LIST_MK_2 t2 ON (t1.MARKET_CATEGORY=t2.MARKET_CATEGORY)
       WHERE SEGMENT in ('B2C','B2B','VIP','OTHER')
             AND t1.ACC_METH in (1, 2)
             AND TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH between &firstmonth. and &lastmonth.
             AND MRGN_ID=&MR.
       GROUP BY t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, t1.REGION, "SEGMENT", t1.ACC_METH, t1.BASE_AGE,'Tип ДЗ'n, t1.ACC_N, 'Amount_of_Debt'n, "DEBT_EXPENSE")
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ACC_N) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;)
by teradata;

EXECUTE (create multiset volatile table Debt_&mon. AS 
(SELECT 
          t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
          t1.REGION,
          t1.SEGMENT,
          t1.ACC_METH,
          COUNT(t1.ACC_N) as Count_ACC_N,
          SUM(t1.NATIONAL_UNPAID) AS NATIONAL_UNPAID,
          SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as DEBT_EXPENSE,
          SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as NATIONAL_AMOUNT,
          (case when SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT)=0 then 0 else (cast(SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as Decimal(20,6))/cast(SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as Decimal(20,6)) end) as 'РСДЗ/Д'n,
          (case when SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE)=0 then 0 else cast(SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as Decimal(20,6))/cast(SUM(t1.DEBT_EXPENSE) as Decimal(20,6)) end) as 'Д/ДЗ'n

       FROM Prev_Debt_&mon. t1
       LEFT JOIN CLC_&mon. t2 on 
            t1.REGION=t2.REGION and
            t1.SEGMENT=t2.SEGMENT and
            t1.ACC_METH=t2.ACC_METH
       GROUP BY t1.TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, t1.REGION, t1.SEGMENT, t1.ACC_METH)

WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;)
by teradata;


Create table RSDZ_&mon. as select
      TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH FORMAT=Date9.,
      REGION FORMAT=FSRGC.,
      SEGMENT FORMAT=$9.,
      ACC_METH FORMAT=F78C.,
      Count_ACC_N,
      NATIONAL_UNPAID FORMAT=NUMX16.2 ,
      DEBT_EXPENSE FORMAT=NUMX16.2,
      NATIONAL_AMOUNT FORMAT=NUMX16.2,
      'РСДЗ/Д'n FORMAT=NUMX16.10,
      'Д/ДЗ'n FORMAT=NUMX16.10

from connection to teradata
(select distinct
      TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH,
      REGION,
      SEGMENT,
      ACC_METH,
      Count_ACC_N,
      NATIONAL_UNPAID,
      DEBT_EXPENSE,
      NATIONAL_AMOUNT,
      'РСДЗ/Д'n,
      'Д/ДЗ'n

    GROUP BY TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, REGION, SEGMENT, ACC_METH, Count_ACC_N, NATIONAL_UNPAID, DEBT_EXPENSE, NATIONAL_AMOUNT, 'РСДЗ/Д'n, 'Д/ДЗ'n
    ORDER BY TABLE_BUSINESS_MONTH, REGION, SEGMENT, ACC_METH

from Debt_&mon.);
```

Comment: Prior to Teradata 15.10, the COUNT() aggregate used INTEGER as it's data type. It is not uncommon to have to CAST the COUNT() function to a DECIMAL(15) or BIGINT when working with large data sets that exceed the INTEGER domain. I would start with `COUNT_ACC_N` as your culprit. SUM() should use the data type of the operand, with some nuances using DECIMAL data with precision.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bigint instead of INTEGER?DECIMAL while casting your numeric columns

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, I found how to solve my problem. I took my code where I had trouble apart from full code. 
The log got the error "Numeric overflow occurred during computation." but sighned that the trouble is with column `NATIONAL_AMOUNT`.
Then I changed my `SUM(t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT) as NATIONAL_AMOUNT,` on `t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT`.
After that code had worked.

I agregated my `t2.NATIONAL_AMOUNT` on previous step and I should'n agregete it twice.